# How to display a large Regression output in RMarkdown (for PDF)

Tags: r, r-markdown, regression, summary, texreg

I am learning different statistical models and how to compute them using R.

I want to display the summary of a large multinomial logistic regression model in RMarkdown so that I am able to generate a PDF file.
However, only one page with the regression results is visible in the generated PDF file. The other results are simply cut off.

This is what I get:
[image]

I have tried the following code to output the summary of my model:

````
```{r, results = 'asis'}
texreg(model_pchoice)
```
````

I expect to generate a nice PDF File with an appealing table (spanning several pages if necessary). How could I proceed?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: First of all the statistical model should be clear and simple following  e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor . More than that the interpretation of each estimate pvalue separately with so many variables is dangerous , please reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction .

Comment: Have you tried the `longtable` argument/package?

Comment: Understand you are wanting PDF output, but Rmarkdown does very well with HTML, you could use an HTML output that has a paged table with search and pivot functionality for your regression table and all the information would be in a single table, instead of spanning multiple pages that can't be filtered.

Comment: It's advisable to use the `knitreg` function instead of the `texreg` function when you work with RMarkdown/`pandoc`. It chooses automatically between HTML and LaTeX, depending on the type of document you create.